# Load image with current date_time using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some images in a folder save automatically from a web camera naming by current date_time. Now i just want to load each image after some seconds(let say 4 sec) which matches to my server current date_time.
Using java script..

I can get server time using PHP

**

> I more simple words, Is there any
>   jquery plugin that load images from
>   folder with respect to image name
>   where the name is based on current
>   date_time?

**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't know the exact server time from from javascript(unless your server and your computer are the same one). Getting time from server using any of the server languages to synchronize time between client and server will not work because of the response time of server. How about another idea. Write a page on server that will return list of last images(or last image), query it with javascript and show the last image(s).

Comment: If you can get server time using php, why not get the file name using php and be done with it?